Using which() with apply
I have two vectors, say
x <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
y <- c("b","e")

I want to derive a vector containing the indices of each item of y within x, that is, c(2,5). How do I vectorize this?
I assume using some variant of apply(), but since which() does not have multiple arguments but rather a single logical statement, I can't figure out how to formulate it - that is, how to provide individual entries of y to which() within the apply() call.
I could loop over y, but since these vectors are actually massive (thousands of entries) that's something to be avoided.
Edit: oh duh - as suggested in the reply linked above, the answer is which(y %in% x). Please feel free to either delete or keep as a "redirect". Cheers

match(y, x) ?
